# Passing php variables to th google.maps javascript method

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps

I am trying to pass two variables (latitude and longitude) to the google.maps.StreetViewPanorama  method without success. Is it possible to do that or I am failing ?

The variables are passing via the url:

```
http://mydomain/street.php?lat=41.653048&lon=-0.880677
```

The code of street.php is:

```
<?php
$lat = $_GET["lat"];
$lon = $_GET["lon"];
?>

<html>
    <head>

        <meta name='viewport' content='width=320,user-scalable=no'/>

        <script src='http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false' type='text/javascript' >
          jlat = <?php echo $lat; ?>
          jlon = <?php echo $lon; ?>
        </script>

    </head>

    <body onload="new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById('p'),
        {position:new google.maps.LatLng(jlat, jlon)
        });"

     style='padding:0px;margin:0px;'>

     <div id='p' style='height:100%;width:100%;'></div>

    </body>
</html>
```

I the  i have fefined the new javescript variable

```
jlat = <?php echo $lat ?>
jlon = <?php echo $lon ?>
```

that hen i pass to the google.maps.LatLng(jlat, jlon), but it doesn't work.

Any idea about that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?  What exactly happens?  As a side note, I would probably declare those two variables with `var lat = ...` and `var lon = ...`

Comment: The scripts works if I do not use the variables, for example:<body onload="new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById('p'),
  {position:new google.maps.LatLng(41.653048, -0.880677)
  });" but doesn't with the variables jlat and jlon

Comment: You still didn't explain what you mean by "doesn't work"  What happens?  What errors are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the way you're writing your javascript is going to work.  Specifically, if you're including javascript from external file, you shouldn't include more code in it.  Try changing your code to this:

```
<?php
$lat = $_GET["lat"];
$lon = $_GET["lon"];
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta name='viewport' content='width=320,user-scalable=no'/>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var jlat = <?php echo $lat ?>;
            var jlon = <?php echo $lon ?>;
        </script>

        <script src='http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false' type='text/javascript' >
        </script>
    </head>

    <body onload="new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById('p'),
        {position:new google.maps.LatLng(jlat, jlon)});" style='padding:0px;margin:0px;'>

     <div id='p' style='height:100%;width:100%;'></div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Didn't you forget a semicolon after $lat = $_GET["lat"]

Comment: +1 for spotting it, although I don't know if this is the root cause.  The OP doesn't really say what he means by "doesn't work"

Answer (score 1):

Now add the semicolons in JavaScript...

```
var jlat = <?php echo $lat ?>;
var jlon = <?php echo $lon ?>;
```

Comment: Thank you, the poroblem was as Aleks G said and semicolons in javascript!